# Why do 3 Vector2s/Points, on a straight line, not have equal angles when split into 2 lines?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector2

As the title says, I'm trying to deduplicate Vector2s that appear on the same line.

My data set looks like this:

```
(197, 59)
(197, 73)
(197, 76)
```

(Obviously, all on the same vertical line)

I've searched for an found lots of answers telling me how to get the Angle of a line between two points (after Normalisation):

```
 float radians = Mathf.Acos(
                   Mathf.Clamp(
                     Vector2.Dot(from, to), 
                       -1f, 1f)));
```

Or

```
float dx = to.x - from.x;
float dy = to.y - from.y;
            
float radians = Math.Atan2(dy, dx)
```

Or

```
   Vector2.Angle(from, to)
```

Or (I'm not sure this is at all right - but I don't think the code is where my problem is)

```
float radians = MathF.Asin(Vector2.Dot(from, to) / from.magnitude+ to.magnitude);
```

But I'm getting a different answer for A->B than from B->C....  Obviously I'm missing something somewhere, but as you might be able to tell my Math knowledge is awful. Could someone point me in the right direction?

You can see the results from `Vector2.Angle()` on my entire data set below:

```
Getting angle of (197.00, 73.82)=>(197.00, 59.52). Normalised: (0.94, 0.35)=>(0.96, 0.29): Result 3.730666
Getting angle of (197.00, 76.62)=>(197.00, 73.82). Normalised: (0.93, 0.36)=>(0.94, 0.35): Result 0.7127182
Getting angle of (183.50, 140.60)=>(197.00, 116.29). Normalised: (0.79, 0.61)=>(0.86, 0.51): Result 6.904529
Getting angle of (197.00, 116.29)=>(197.00, 76.62). Normalised: (0.86, 0.51)=>(0.93, 0.36): Result 9.300751
Getting angle of (190.75, 158.58)=>(183.50, 140.60). Normalised: (0.77, 0.64)=>(0.79, 0.61): Result 2.279588
Getting angle of (197.00, 163.32)=>(190.75, 158.58). Normalised: (0.77, 0.64)=>(0.77, 0.64): Result 0.07661668
Getting angle of (197.00, 59.52)=>(197.00, 163.32). Normalised: (0.96, 0.29)=>(0.77, 0.64): Result 22.85009
```

Result from Mathf.Atans (as above) .... that fact the results are all different not only from each other but from above really shows just how stuck I am:

```
Getting angle of (197.00, 73.82)=>(197.00, 59.52). Normalised: (0.94, 0.35)=>(0.96, 0.29): Result -1.244842
Getting angle of (197.00, 76.62)=>(197.00, 73.82). Normalised: (0.93, 0.36)=>(0.94, 0.35): Result -1.206062
Getting angle of (183.50, 140.60)=>(197.00, 116.29). Normalised: (0.79, 0.61)=>(0.86, 0.51): Result -0.9772647
Getting angle of (197.00, 116.29)=>(197.00, 76.62). Normalised: (0.86, 0.51)=>(0.93, 0.36): Result -1.118683
Getting angle of (190.75, 158.58)=>(183.50, 140.60). Normalised: (0.77, 0.64)=>(0.79, 0.61): Result -0.8971169
Getting angle of (197.00, 163.32)=>(190.75, 158.58). Normalised: (0.77, 0.64)=>(0.77, 0.64): Result 2.263658
Getting angle of (197.00, 59.52)=>(197.00, 163.32). Normalised: (0.96, 0.29)=>(0.77, 0.64): Result 2.063599
```

Atans *without* normalisation gives me the following. Progress!.... I still don't understand anything and would still really appreciate even a link to a tutorial or book or video or something! :D

```
Getting angle of (197.00, 73.82)=>(197.00, 59.52). Normalised: (197.00, 73.82)=>(197.00, 59.52): Result -1.570796
Getting angle of (197.00, 76.62)=>(197.00, 73.82). Normalised: (197.00, 76.62)=>(197.00, 73.82): Result -1.570796
Getting angle of (183.50, 140.60)=>(197.00, 116.29). Normalised: (183.50, 140.60)=>(197.00, 116.29): Result -1.063928
Getting angle of (197.00, 116.29)=>(197.00, 76.62). Normalised: (197.00, 116.29)=>(197.00, 76.62): Result -1.570796
Getting angle of (190.75, 158.58)=>(183.50, 140.60). Normalised: (190.75, 158.58)=>(183.50, 140.60): Result -1.953735
Getting angle of (197.00, 163.32)=>(190.75, 158.58). Normalised: (197.00, 163.32)=>(190.75, 158.58): Result -2.492572
Getting angle of (197.00, 59.52)=>(197.00, 163.32). Normalised: (197.00, 59.52)=>(197.00, 163.32): Result 1.570796
```

(Removing Normalisation from Vector2.Angle() gives the same results.... Why?!)

Comment: You have three points, or three vectors? Because dot product is for vectors and you seem to go by points. Atan2 should give the same result if they’re on the same line, but since you haven’t shown what results you get from these it’s hard to say

Comment: Have Edited. When I say Vector, I mean Vector2, Aka Point

Comment: What do you get for `Math.Atan2` that’s incorrect? Because for me both are the same for A->B and B->C as it should be

Comment: I've included full debugging from my whole data set. Not all are on the same line, but most are.

Comment: And added the Dataset from Atans

Comment: There is no such thing as an "angle" between two points. Did you mean to calculate a heading? A heading involves a second direction the heading is based on such as north or maybe `Vector2.up` in your case. Also, are you normalizing positions?

Comment: It makes little sense to `Normalize` positions! This only makes sense for **directions** ...

Comment: You’re normalizing *points* for some reason. This of course changes everything. Don’t do that and everything works.

Comment: Thank you, all reasonable comments. I understood normalization to mean changing a point to have an even length. With your questions I realised points don't have length. But may I ask in response to what you've just said.... How is a vector different than a point? Are they not both wraps around two numbers?

Comment: @Graeme https://math.stackexchange.com/q/645672/611585

Comment: Thank you Ruzihm! This is certainly a field that is simple... But only when you already know it. This helps a lot as it gives me the language I need.

Comment: Just to add to @Ruzihm 's link: a position is basically a vector from world origin `0,0,0` towards your position. If you normalize that you get a new position in the same direction from origin but exactly 1 unit away from it. Since your points are originally on a straight line, after normalizing them they will actually be placed on the edge of a circle with radius 1 around the world origin, so in an arc. You can imagine that this way the angle of course will never be 0 / 180 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Vector" can mean different things depending on contexts. In a geometric context it usually represent either a *point* or a *direction*. The term 'vector' is sometimes used interchangeably with direction, but I think it it use useful to be more specific.

When computing angles they must represent *directions* since taking the angle of two points is meaningless. So you need to convert the points to directions. For example by taking the direction from the central point to the left and right points:

```
var direction1 = myPoints[0] - myPoints[1];
var direction2 = myPoints[2] - myPoints[1];
 var angle = Vector2.Angle(direction1 , direction2 );
```

and you should get an angle for half a circle.

I would argue that it would be clearer to use distinct `Point2` and `Direction2` types to avoid any confusion or misuse. And while some vector libraries has taken that approach, Unity3D have not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - your really helping me gain understanding. May I ask, the example you have shows 3 points. Can you get an angle of a direction relative to an axis?

Comment: @Graeme Sure, just use the direction as one parameter for the Angle-function, and the direction of the reference axis as the other.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is where googling fails me. Would that be 4 points?  Direction of a reference axis would be 0,0 / 0,1 for instance?

Comment: @Graeme the direction of a reference axis would for example be (1, 0) for the X-axis, and (0, 1) for the Y-axis. But you can in principle use any direction. Note that the zero-vector, (0,0), is *not* a direction, since it lacks length.

Comment: Dang it. Thank you for taking the time. I appreciate it.